# React useRef scrollIntoView only fires once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm trying to scroll to an element when it comes into view. The problem is that it only works on a reload when it's already in view.

I've tried debugging it, but the ref seems to be correct and the conditionals pass. There is no return or error message so I don't know how to debug this further.

The hook works as it should so I'm really struggling to figure out what the cause is...

I need to put this in useEffect later on, but even this basic setup doesn't work. Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: I need to get this in the center of the screen so that I can overtake the scroll and animate the element on scroll. If I already start that functionality without it being centered, it'll stick to the bottom of the screen while it animates.

#### This is the component

```
const Component = () => {
    const sectionRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const isOnScreen = useOnScreen(sectionRef);
    
    if (isOnScreen && sectionRef?.current) {
        sectionRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'nearest'});
    }
    
    return ( 
        <section ref={sectionRef}>
            // ...child components
        </section>
    )
}

export default Component
```

#### This is the hook

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, RefObject } from 'react';

export default function useOnScreen(ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const observerRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);
  const [isOnScreen, setIsOnScreen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
      setIsOnScreen(entry.isIntersecting)
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
        observerRef.current?.observe(ref.current);
    }

    return () => {
      observerRef.current?.disconnect();
    };
  }, [ref]);

  return isOnScreen;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, `scroll to an element when it comes into view` if it's already in view, why do you need to scroll to that element?

Comment: @NickVu Because I need to center it in the screen so that I can then overtake the scroll and animate some things in the element. If I trigger that when it's slightly visible, it'll stay locked in the bottom of the screen while the animations happen.